# How to pass array of object through web api to a List<> using angular js

Tags: javascript, c#, arrays, angularjs

here is my array in controller:

```
$scope.arr = [];

    $scope.arr.push({

        QuestionId1: firstQuestionId,
        QuestionId2: secondQuestionId,
         SecurityAnswer1: firstQuestionAnswer,
         SecurityAnswer2: secondQuestionAnswer
        });
```

AccountService.SubmitSecurityAnswer($scope);

then here is my api in angular service:

```
fact.SubmitSecurityAnswer = function (d) {
    debugger;
    return $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: API_RESOURCES.API_Domain + 'api/Account/SaveSecurityAnswers',
        headers: { 'content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
        transformRequest: function (obj) {

            var str = [];
            for (var p in obj)
                str.push(encodeURIComponent(p) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(obj[p]));
            return str.join("&");
        },
        isArray: true,

        data: d.arr

        }).success(function (response) {
        return response;
```

The C# function which this api calls is:

```
 public HttpResponseMessage SaveSecurityAnswers(List<SecurityQuestion_CustomerMap> obj)
    {
```

When I check 'obj' through break point it shows count=0..I think the format of 'data: d.arr' is not right or is it?
Please help.

Comment: try changing the content-type to application/JSON, and removing the transformFormRequest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your client code make the following changes to pass the request as json. I'm assuming that the list of objects is added inside of another object that you are passing in (d)? If not then drop the .arr in the JSON.stringify just send "d" if it is the list of objects.

```
fact.SubmitSecurityAnswer = function (d) {
    return $http({
        url: API_RESOURCES.API_Domain + 'api/Account/SaveSecurityAnswers',
        dataType: 'json',
        method: 'POST',
        data: JSON.stringify(d.arr),
        headers: {
           "Content-Type": "application/json"
        }
    });
}
```

And change your endpoint to look for the list of objects in the body of the request.

```
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage SaveSecurityAnswers([FromBody]List<SecurityQuestion_CustomerMap> obj)
```